# Tweet counter for identi.ca

Tags: json, api, statusnet, identica

Is there a way to retrieve the amount of times a certain URL was "dented" (shared on identi.ca, status.net and/or the likes?).

For twitter there are several services that give this information.

- Twitter itself: http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://example.com&callback=twttr.receiveCount
- Tweetmeme: http://api.tweetmeme.com/url_info.jsonc?url=http://example.com
- Topsy: http://otter.topsy.com/stats.js?url=http://example.com&callback=?

I don't need the fancy extra information that Tweetmeme or Topsy deliver, only the amount.

I am aware that this is problematic, seen from the "distributed" nature of status.net: it will only give a count from once single silo, e.g. identi.ca. However, for me, for now, that would be enough.

Is there such an endpoint that gives me such JSON?

Comment: Does my comment answer your question? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, It does :(. I did not accept it yet, because I was hoping someone might offer an alternative still.

Comment: There is also a proposed Google Summer of Code project for StatusNet that would do that (among other things), a Social Analytics Plugin: http://status.net/wiki/Google_Summer_of_Code_2011#Social_Analytics_Plugin.

I'll update my answer to add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. There's a `file` table in StatusNet databases that holds references to dented URLs (so it wouldn't be hard to count them if you had access to database or could write a plugin -- i.e., you wouldn't have to parse all notices, just lookup the `file` table), but it's not exposed through the API.

The list of API possible calls for StatusNet is here: http://status.net/wiki/TwitterCompatibleAPI

In addition, there's a proposed Google Summer of Code project on this subject: [Social Analytics plugin](http://status.net/wiki/Google_Summer_of_Code_2011#Social_Analytics_Plugin)